# Connection refused on localhost:2181

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have setup a Kalka server for TRON's eventsListener plugin by following the steps that show on the correspondence website. I got the error when I start the server, please see the error as below.

```
Unable to connect to the zookeeper server localhost:2181 with timeout of 6000ms.

[2019-04-09 02:04:13,196] FATAL Fatal error during KafkaServerStartable startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server '127.0.0.1:2181' with timeout of 6000 ms
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:1233)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:157)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:131)
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.createZkClientAndConnection(ZkUtils.scala:106)
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.apply(ZkUtils.scala:88)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZk(KafkaServer.scala:326)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:187)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:39)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:67)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2019-04-09 02:04:13,197] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

Comment: Is there some error while starting zookeeper server?

Comment: @MukeshPrajapati - Yes, just saw it. The error before that is " Failed creating the log file in the particular directory." Does it means if I resolved the first error the server should be up & running?

Comment: Yupp... It should work fine once server is running. Make sure Kafka has write permission for creating log file.

Comment: /usr/local/kafka/bin/../logs/state-change.log(Permission denied). I granted the 777 permission to the directory (/usr/local/kafka), still no lucks :(

Comment: Can you try granting permission to `logs` directory.

Comment: After I resolved the previous error, it comes a new error. " Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL."

Comment: Please update your question with error you are getting.

Comment: That "SASL" line is a warning, not an error

Comment: Other than that, I don't see any others error. Please advise.

Comment: I have updated the error message above.

Comment: Can you try solution mentioned on [kafka-cant-connect-to-zookeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17668262/kafka-cant-connect-to-zookeeper-fatal-fatal-error-during-kafkaserverstable-star)

Comment: Besides, I tried to telnet to the Ubuntu server that sitting on Azure Cloud. Here is the command "telnet hostname 2181", I got the "Connection Refused" error. Are these two errors are relevant? I have got the specific port 2181 open on the firewall.

Comment: The advertised.host.name and advertised.host.port are null in the server.properties config. Where should I set those?